# Which SQL Server Manager should I use: C:\Windows\System32 or C:\Windows\SysWOW64?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I need to access the SQL Server Manager. However, I've noticed that there are two different paths to access it: `C:\Windows\System32\SQLServerManager16.msc` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager16.msc`. I'm not sure which one to use. Can anyone explain the difference between these two paths and which one is the recommended one to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My **SQL Server Configuration Manager** points to:

```
C:\Windows\system32\SQLServerManager16.msc
```

This is the 64-Bit version of SSCM. If you are running SQL Server on 64-Bit version of a Windows Operating System, which is the norm nowadays, then I would chose this version over the other.

The other path points to the 32-Bit version of SSCM:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager16.msc
```

The `SysWOW64` directory is generally where the 32-Bit versions of programs are stored.

The `system32` directory is where the 64-Bit versions of programs are stored.

Further reading can be found in the Microsoft Learn article [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

> The **%windir%\System32** directory is reserved for **64-bit applications** on **64-bit Windows**. Most DLL file names were not changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs were created, so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a different directory. WOW64 hides this difference by using a file system redirector.

Yes, it is confusing.

Comment: Worth explaining: inside 32-bit programs, "system32" points to syswow64 (that is how they trick a lot of 32-bit programs into not crashing) and I think to access the real system32 it's called sysnative. If you go to open a file inside a 32-bit program you will see these fake folders.

Answer (score 2):

As addition to the previous answer:

It actually does not matter which version of SSCM you would use with a 64 bit server. Both 64 bit SSCM and 32 bit SSCM are fully capable to work with the server without any issues. In theory, in case of bit-wise mismatch, you can see some loss of performance if you are working with big data types, but the actual loss would be measured in picoseconds.

Same goes for connection drivers - since they are build as dynamic libraries, they have to match the client application, but they do not have to match the server.